# Problems with section numbering style

Tags: cfr-lm

Could you please tell me what's going on? Number 3 is one step below number one and so forth

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your document seems to use old style numbers for its chapter and section numbering.

Comment: I am using `\usepackage{cfr-lm}` instead of `\usepackage{lmordern}`. maybe it has to do with that`??

Comment: I have removed the `hyperref` and `babel` tags since both packages seem to be unrelated to the issue. I have added `cfr-lm` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following MWE reproduces the issue and clearly shows that `cfr-lm` is the cause for the old style numbers.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Taking a look at its documentation, we find:

> By default, the LATEX package provided by `cfr-lm.sty` uses
> proportional oldstyle digits and variable width typewriter but this
> can be changed by passing appropriate options when loading the
> package.

Depending on the output you want, you could add an option such as `rm={oldstyle=false}`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[rm={oldstyle=false}]{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}

\end{document}
```

[image]